# How to do INSERT INTO SELECT and ON DUPLICATE UPDATE in PostgreSQL 9.5?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to to do the following in PostgreSQL

```
INSERT INTO blog_sums ( blog_id, date, total_comments)
    SELECT blog_id, '2016-09-22', count(comment_id) as total_comments_update
    FROM blog_comments
    WHERE date = '2016-09-22'
    GROUP BY blog_id         
ON CONFLICT (blog_id ,date)
DO UPDATE SET blog_sums.total_comments = total_comments_update;
```

I have unique key on date + blog_id and I keep getting Error:

> ERROR:  column "total_comments_update" does not exist

I'm looking for the "right" way and the most efficient way to do update on duplicate/conflict in this case

my tables are

```
blog_comments (blog_id, comment_id, comment, date)
blog_sums ( blog_id, date, total_comments) . unique on blog_id+date
```

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You cannot access the column aliases from the select in the `DO UPDATE SET` clause. You can use the `excluded` table alias which includes all rows that failed to insert because of conflicts:

```
INSERT INTO blog_sums ( blog_id, date, total_comments)
    SELECT blog_id, '2016-09-22', count(comment_id) as total_comments_update
    FROM blog_comments
    WHERE date = '2016-09-22'
    GROUP BY blog_id         
ON CONFLICT (blog_id ,date)
DO UPDATE SET total_comments = excluded.total_comments;
```

So `excluded.total_comments` in the last line refers to the value of `total_comments` that we tried to insert but we couldn't, because of the conflict.

Comment: Don't forget the GROUP BY or you'll get (with postgresql 9.6.1): 

ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time

HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.